# How can we customize WooCommerce product category page without creating new page and redirect?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

My research tells me we can customize the category page by redirecting our category pages to new pages that are customized. How can we can customize the category page without redirecting to a new page with code? Can we use code along the lines of: `If category=Clothing > show "X" ?...but if category=Shoes > show "Y"`?

Comment: Are you asking about WordPress Conditionals ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags ), like is_category('Clothing') and is_category('Shoes')? or WordPress Templates ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates ) like category-clothing.php and category-shoes.php?

Comment: @PhilF Sorry but this question is about WooCommerce product category (a custom taxonomy) with specific WooCommerce templates, so nothing to do with WordPress.

Comment: @I60883817 You can [override WooCommerce templates via your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) and you can also use all related hooks too. Also see [WooCommerce conditional tags - product category page](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-5) like `is_product_category()`

Comment: Ah, so WooCommerce categories are just WordPress custom taxonomies, so you'd want is_tax('product_cat', 'Clothing') or is_tax('product_cat', 'Shoes') from WordPress Conditionals or use the WooCommerce helpers linked above from your comment

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thank you. example on second link you provided is exact code I needed: `if ( is_product_category() ) {
  
  if ( is_product_category( 'shirts' ) ) {
    echo 'Hi! Take a look at our sweet tshirts below.';
  } elseif ( is_product_category( 'games' ) ) {
    echo 'Hi! Hungry for some gaming?';
  } else {
    echo 'Hi! Check our our products below.';
  }

}`